# How to implement table pagination with previous and next button using jQuery and Bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, pagination, bootstrap-4

I have created bootstrap table with 79 rows. I am showing only 10 rows at a time and rest in the form of pagination. I am able to create pagination. How to implement previous and next button and disable it as well if there are no pages left to display?

```
JS fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/tb74dqex/1/
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `disabled` property to your `page-item` via your JavaScript file.

Something like:

```
$("#page-item-id").addClass("disabled");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add an `.on('click')` listener on the buttons itself, see below:

```
function activePage() { // helps us get the current active page
    var $el = $('[data-page].active');

  if($el.length) {
    return $el.data('page');
  }

  return false;
}

$(function() {
  $('.prev-btn, .next-btn').on('click', function(e) { // watch for click events
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation(); // prevent the parent elements event from firing

    // If the clicked element has "prev-btn" class, -1 else +1 to current page
    var page = activePage() + ($(event.target).hasClass('prev-btn') ? -1 : 1);

    // Find the data-page that matches and simulate a click
    $('[data-page="' + page + '"]').trigger('click');
  });
})
```

See fiddle for working example: https://jsfiddle.net/8bg4dxes/

The above solution compliments the existing code without needing to re-write everything.

It is worth noting that you cannot add a `disabled` attribute on `a` tags like this:

```
<a href="#" disabled>Link</a>
```

The solution provided above will simply not do anything on click if there is no text page.

Comment: Glad to hear! If you're happy with the result, always remember to mark it as the correct answer so we can help anyone else looking for this :)